# android service crashes after sometime

Tags: java, android, service

I've Created an service  for lock screen service the purpose of the service is to register and unregistered receiver but it is causing memory leak because of the my application crashes when there is not enough memory left to consume 
Here is my code

```
    package com.itstars.daynightlockscreen;

import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.app.KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LockService extends Service {
    public static boolean wal;
    public static boolean isRunning;

    public static TimeChangeReceiver receiver;
     KeyguardManager keyguardManager;
     KeyguardLock lock;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        keyguardManager  = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Service.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        lock.disableKeyguard();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        wal = intent.getBooleanExtra("wal", false);
        isRunning = intent.getBooleanExtra("locker",false);
        receiver = new TimeChangeReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        isRunning = true;
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        isRunning = false;
        keyguardManager  = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Service.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        lock.reenableKeyguard();
    }


}
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.itstars.daynightlockscreen.LockService@41e23c30 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2771)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:157)
at

Comment: The above exception is not because of memory leak i guess. You are trying to start service on Null intent (com.itstars.daynightlockscreen.LockService@41e23c30 with null). Could you send the code for how you are starting the service.

Comment: i'm starting the service from here in main activity 
   if(locker.isChecked())  
      {
       Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,LockService.class);
       i.putExtra("locker", true);
       i.putExtra("wal",chk.isChecked());
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       startService(i);
      }
      else
      {
       Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,LockService.class);
       stopService(i);
      }

Answer (score 0):

Have you define Service in Manifest? If Yes,
  then Have you give permission

```
`android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD`
```

in manifest ? If yes, then
Put a code in try-catch block in onStartCommand , put a debug point on first line of onStartCommand method observe line where it jump to catch block.
Because error must be in your onStartCommand method only.

START_NOT_STICKY

Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), and there are no new start intents to deliver to it, then take the service out of the started state and don't recreate until a future explicit call to Context.startService(Intent).

START_STICKY

Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent.

Using above description decide where you want to use sticky intent or not ?

Comment: I did what you said but i don't if it works or not because this exception is thrown when mobile is at low memory and i forget one thing this server is  consuming 35mb of ram is it normal

Comment: It is a normal that service is being used  that much memory

Comment: i followed your instructions and the application is running normal now but if any error occur in future i will inform you

Comment: application is still trowing null pointer exception in service I've notice that when mobile is low on memory or busy in some task then application throws null pointer exception

Comment: I'm using startapp add on my application on main activity this service is running another activity on screen off but the add sometimes load on this activity i don't know why but is this causing the null pointer exception

Comment: Did you debug the app ? at what point it jumps on catch block ?

Comment: when system is on low memory other applications like facebook stops and starts automatically but my service does not start automatically